# Redis multi behavior in cluster mode

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

When working with a single redis instance I can be sure that commands inside MULTI will be processed as a single atomic operation.

What happens when redis operates in cluster mode?

Can I be sure slaves won't get intermediate result of MULTI but only the whole/none of commands that were send as a MULTI(transaction)?

added: all commands inside MULTI operating on the same slot and keys are tagged with {tagName}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis' replication between master and slave(s) is designed to honor `MULTI`'s assurances, so yeah, you can be sure. Put differently, the replication stream that the slave gets is a built out of the write operations that the master performs. These are sent in order, and since `MULTI` guarantees atomicity on the master, it follows that the same applies to the slaves.

Comment: Does the same apply to lua calls? Will slave automatically get all scripts that exists on master and in the same right order?

Comment: Oh yeah (unless there's a bug somewhere... ;))